# How to create autocomplete JComboBox in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox

I am new to Java.  I am stuck at a place. I need to create an editable `JComboBox` which fires event every time when typed value is changed.

For example if there are 100 items in combo box then when user type 'a' in editable combo box then the drop down menu only shows that items which starts from 'a' only.

Comment: if my answer is helpful you can select my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this example of  [autocomplete JComboBox](http://www.algosome.com/articles/java-jcombobox-autocomplete.html). Detail explanation with example is  given there.